# Using Redirect to access generated URL

Tags: django, django-views

I intend rerouting to a URL generated in my view. I'm trying to use redirect but it throws: 'localhost' is not a registered namespace in my local server. I need the functionality of auto generating this URL so i won't hardcode in production.

```
class SignUp(FormView):
    template_name = 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html'
    form_class = ClientForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = ClientForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'blogApi/tenant_registration.html', context)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        url = self.request.get_host()
        print(name+"."+url)
        Client.objects.create(name=name, schema_name=name, domain_url=name+".localhost")
        return redirect(url)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import SignUp

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUp.as_view(), name="sign_up"),
    path('home', include('blogApi.urls', namespace="blog"), name='home'),

]
```

Comment: try `redirect('home')`

Comment: Redirect home would redirect to localhost:8000/home. However, I intend redirecting to name.localhost:8000/home

Comment: [`redirect(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function will also take absolute and relative URLs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a different domain, don't use `redirect`, you have to generate the full url and just return it in `form_valid`